# sql 2008 procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

```
CREATE PROCEDURE csGorevDuzenle
 @duzenle int,
 @grup_ad varchar(30), 
 @islem_grubu varchar(30),
 @tamamlayan varchar(30),
 @kayit_zamani datetime,
 @sonuc_zamani varchar(30),
 @arayan varchar(30),
 @telefon varchar(20),
 @tanim varchar(1000),
 @durum varchar(15),
 @aciklama varchar(1000)
AS

  if @duzenle = 1 then
BEGIN
 UPDATE gorevler SET grup_ad = @islem_grubu, tamamlayan = @tamamlayan, sonuc_zamani = @sonuc_zamani, arayan = @arayan, telefon = @telefon, tanim = @tanim, durum = @durum, aciklama = @aciklama
 WHERE grup_ad = @grup_ad and kayit_zamani = @kayit_zamani 
END

  end if
GO
```

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure csGorevDuzenle, Line 20
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'then'.
>   Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure csGorevDuzenle, Line 26
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'if'.

Comment: Please ask a question. Just posting a SP and error message is not asking a question.

Answer (score 2):

This is not correct SQL syntax for an [IF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717.aspx) statement:

```
if @duzenle = 1 then
```

change to:

```
IF ( @duzenle = 1 )
```

Answer (score 1):

T-SQL doesn't require you to write THEN after the IF statement. Change it to the following and it will work:

```
if @duzenle = 1 
BEGIN
```